# ASP.NET MVC Editing a navigation collection property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to update an entity's collection navigation property, but i'm pretty sure i'm not going about it the right way. In my application i made a User And Role Model and because a user can belong to more than 1 role and roles can have many users i modeled it like this

User with some fields omitted for briefty:

```
 public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserHasRoles { get; set; } 
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserRole { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserHasRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I've made a view model that i give to the view so you can select new roles for the User:

```
public class UserWithRoleViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public List<int> RoleIds { get; set; }
}
```

After receiving the view model in my [HttpPost] action method of my controller i pass it on to my repository and try to update the User with the roles chosen:

```
public void SaveChangesToUser(UserWithRoleViewModel model)
    {
        model.User.UserHasRoles = new List<UserRole>();

        foreach (var id in model.RoleIds)
        {
            model.User.UserHasRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserId = model.User.Id, RoleId = id });
        }
        _context.Entry(model.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I try to clear the old values from the navigation property and insert new ones, but it dosen't work. Updating the other user properties works fine, but not the navigation properties. So my questions are, why isen't this working and am i even trying to do this the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I take it back, I see what you are doing, try the code below

```
public void SaveChangesToUser(UserWithRoleViewModel model)
{
    model.User.UserHasRoles = new List<UserRole>();

    _context.Entry(model.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
    foreach (var id in model.RoleIds)
    {
        var userRole = new UserRole { UserId = model.User.Id, RoleId = id };
        model.User.UserHasRoles.Add(userRole);
        _context.Entry(userRole).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I think you have to set the state of all the children too.

Another note, I agree with @Simon, you don't need UserRole object, you can just map to a associate table in db and just have `ICollection<Role>` in User and `ICollection<User>` in Role.

in your mapping

```
        HasMany(c => c.Users).WithMany(c => c.Roles).Map(r =>
        {
            r.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
            r.MapRightKey("UserId");
            r.ToTable("RoleUser");
        });
```

Comment: actually he can keep the roleUser model it can sometimes help if you wish to handle common scalar attributes. I recommend leaving it there just remove the ID since the primary key will be a combination of the two foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you when you have some common attributes, but you can always add it when you need it. YAGNI :)

Answer (score 0):

For a many to many relationship in entity framework, you will need to use the fluent API and declare your relationships. 
First of all, an association class should not have it's own Primary key.

```
public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Remove the Id in UserRole, the UserId and RoleId will compose it's primary together. Now that the models are properly design, we need to create the modelbuilder for the relationship:

In your databasecontext class:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
                        .HasKey(cp => new { cp.UserId, cp.RoleId })
                        .Map(q=>q.ToTable("UserRole")); //your database table name

     modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                        .Map(q =>q.ToTable("User"))
                        .HasMany(c => c.UserRole)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.UserId) //points on the UserId in UserRole table
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(); //should handle cascade deletes
     modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                        .Map(q =>q.ToTable("Role"))
                        .HasMany(c => c.UserRole)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.RoleId)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
 }
```

Make sure your mappings use the proper table names. Note that the names used in the lambdas are completely random and subject to changes on your own desires.